# Videos I upload do not play audio on mobile devices but work fine on desktop

Tags: youtube, mobile, audio

As the title says, my issue is that videos I upload do not play audio on mobile devices but work fine on desktop. I've confirmed this with other users as well, so this is not just a problem with my phone. I've also tried using both the m.you.com page and the YouTube app. I'm on an iOS device and I've also been told it's the same on Android devices.

Here are a couple of examples:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zyug68kO2Vo
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QwzD0es-Tkg

I use Adobe Premiere to edit and use one of the YouTube defaults to render to. Specifically "YouTube HD 1080p 29.97" which is a H.264 format. The file type is .mp4.

Any help as to why this happens would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hmmm, visiting http://m.youtube.com/watch?client=mv-google&hl=en&gl=US&v=Zyug68kO2Vo on a computer, I can pull up the rtsp:// link in VLC, and indeed there is no audio. Appears Google has messed up transcoding it... Maybe try a different audio codec in your upload?

Answer (score 1):

If the video contains audio that may be subject to copyright, then the copyright holder has the ability to restrict playback in various ways. Some ways they do this could be the following:

- Disabling audio on mobile devices
- Disabling audio on any viewing platform
- Disabling playback on mobile devices
- Placing ads on the video
- Blocking playback of video with a message saying the video had a copyright claim filed

Of course there may be a few other cases of things that they will do, but in this case the issue is most likely due to copyrights.